# How can an unused variable can be indicative of bug(s)?

Tags: recycle-bin

Language type doesn't matter here; it can be functional; procedural, imperative, object oriented... or it doesn't have to be the case in a language at all. This question applies to the language that can have unused variable/code.

What type of this bug will be? How does not using something extra qualify as a bug?

A little background: though I read it on F# [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2012/07/19/more-about-fsharp-3.0-language-features.aspx), it seems like language agnostic to me; after all you can have unused variable in any program in any language.

Comment: Language type **does** matter here, your question makes absolutely no sense for dynamic languages - there is no such thing as an unused variable in python, and you can't even reliably check if a variable is used or not.

Comment: so you can't have an `SystemName = "Super-PC-001"` just lying there in python code? Last line is interesting. F# and C# and C and CPP compilers tell programmer that there are unused variables in the code. What are you talking about?

Comment: In fact, various Python code checking tools *do* issue warnings for variables that appear to be unused. They just aren't 100% accurate. For example, consider the python code `import sys; foo = 'bar'; print locals().get(sys.argv[1], None)`. Then the variable `foo` is used if the first command line argument is "foo", unused otherwise. A static code analysis tool probably can't usefully decide whether it's used or unused.

Comment: What I meant is you can't declare a variable and not assign anything to it, and you can dynamically access local, global or member variables. consider this function: `def f(can,you,guess,the,name,of,an,argument): print locals().get(raw_input("guess a variable name: "), "guessed wrong!")` - it asks the user to guess the name of the arguments of the function, if it matches it prints the value. either all or all but one of the variables are unused, but you can't check for it. Of course this is not a real-world example, but similar code using `getattr`, `locals` or `globals` is not uncommon.

Answer (score 2):

The case where I've actually seen a warning for unused variables (or unused parameters) catch a bug is something like this:

```
start = 1
stop = 10
do_something(start, start, other_data)
```

`stop` is unused, *because I typed the wrong thing*, and luckily the warning would lead me to identify the bug. Obviously there are other ways to catch that bug (testing), and there are instances of that bug that wouldn't be caught this way because the variable is still used elsewhere.

Generally an unused variable is just a warning that the code isn't written as the author really intended (because normally you don't *want* an unused variable). Doesn't necessarily mean it's buggy, just that you might like to write it differently.

Comment: Good example - and a strong argument for fixing "unused variable"/"unused parameter" warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example where an unused variable may mask a bug until the unused variable is removed:

```
int a[10];
int b[10]; // unused
int c[10];

// initialise a
for (i = 0; i <= 10; ++i)
    a[i] = i; // out of bounds write to a when i = 10
```

In the above case the out of bounds write to a happens to overwrite the start of an unused array (`b`) and so doesn't have any harmful effects (this is known as a *latent* bug). When the unused array is removed then the start of `c` gets overwritten instead.

(Note that the above example is compiler-dependent - it assumes that `b` doesn't get optimised away by a smart compiler and that arrays are allocated sequentially and contiguously, but the general principle is nonetheless valid.)

Comment: It's also interesting that in both of our examples, "remove the unused variable" is *not* the correct response to the warning. In your case it's the correct first step but it's not the full fix needed, in my case it's incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Since, I have never written functions/methods longer than 100 lines, I don't know when or how following things happen but some scenarios I can think of involve:

There can be code that has been modified; now useless.

There can be code that is just dead because of many such modifications. Dead code is problematic in large code base; as programmer has to read it almost every time and can't tweak (remove) it because then he would require a serious bug testing. Tweaking code for bugs produces bugs of other type.

Unused variable shows the lack of planning or implementing. Initially required by specification but now still unused because of further delay or because specification stayed same.

May be an interface kind of thing implemented too early too soon. Now, API is public...

In language that has preprocessor (sort of) directives that can modify code based on the environment or type of build; a lot of variables can be unused. like Debug and Release conditions in C#. That can be marked as a bug, as in "it might be a bug in different build or condition"

Other than that, I am still looking for answers.

Comment: "I have never written functions/methods longer than 100 lines". Good. Functions longer than 100 lines should maybe carry a warning too. They're not *necessarily* wrong :-)

Comment: I meant, I write short concise functions that do only one thing in their life. Anything re-usable goes to another function. So, never even saw this warning before.